# Is it possible to install Team Foundation Server 2010 with a free version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Is there a way to install Team Foundation Server 2010 with a free version of SQL Server(Express Edition)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: The information below the line applied to TFS2010 Beta 1 (and earlier).

As of Beta 2 (and continued with RC and RTM) you can install TFS on:

- SQL Server Express
- SQL Server Standard
- SQL Server Enterprise

TFS includes options to install with Express (e.g. run on your own client system), and a licence for Standard (only when installing as a single, data & application tier together, server).

---

Quick answer: No.

Longer answer: Take a look at the ["Team Foundation Installation Guide for Visual Studio Team System 2010"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f) which says, under "Installing Prerequisites" [sic] | SQL Server:

> Supported editions:
>
> - SQL Server 2008, Standard Edition
> - SQL Server 2008, Enterprise Edition

Additional: I haven't checked this, but for test/evaluation/development (of TFS/VS addins) the Development Edition may also work.

Comment: @Richard - you could get my +1 if you update your answer (see new answers). Thanks!

Comment: @splattne: Done.

Answer (score 3):

This has actually changed with the Beta 2 version of TFS 2010.  One of the configuration options, "Basic", allows the use of SQL Server Express (and will even install it for you, I believe).  The page that Richard linked to actually contains the Beta 2 version of the installation guide as well, which documents this feature.

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer is not correct. TFS 2010 Basic install will run on SQL Server Express (free). And if you have SQL Server (standard or better) included with your MSDN subscription you get a licence to use that in production for TFS only. Please see this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2009/10/20/tfs-2010-server-licensing-it-s-included-in-msdn-subscriptions.aspx